# Fancybox script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have used Fancybox on multiple occasions and never run into this problem. I have included both jQuery and Fancybox files in the header, linked up the first order button the the page to open up an iframe in a Fancybox. However I cant seem to get it to work at all. It doesn't open an iframe and instead goes straight to the page I was trying to open inside the Fancybox iframe.

Can somebody point out whatever blindingly obvious mistake I've made this horrible Monday morn?

Testing server can be found here:

http://www.designti.me/testing/flipstick/original.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'fancybox'`

Which implies that fancybox hasn't loaded. Taking a close look at your source we see `<script type="text/x-ecmascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>` which you can see uses x-ecmascript rather than javascript. Change that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put your code into the `ready` handler:

```
$(function() {                   // <-- you need this
    $("a.iframe").fancybox({ 
        //...
    });
});                              // <-- and this
```

Comment: @Alexander 'Bambi' Sadler: Well as you can see from the other answers, this seems not to be the only error ;) You have to do both!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to put it in document.ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.iframe").fancybox({
         'width' : '75%',
         'height' : '75%',
         'autoScale' : false,
         'transitionIn' : 'none',
         'transitionOut' : 'none',
         'type' : 'iframe'
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
      jQuery("a.iframe").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',  //<--missing comma here
        'width':750,
        'height':500  //<-- removed last comma here
    });
```

});